# Replace number larger than a number in several columns

Tags: awk

I want to replace those number larger than one by one (leaving 0 as 0) in my matrix using awk. My tried was using:

```
awk '$2>1 {$2=1} 1'
```

But, I could not find the way to select more than one column (I have 30).
And also it would be great if I can avoid replacing the characters of the header.
For example, if my table is:

```
Species  Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3
Species_1   15      4         0
Species_2   10      3         2
```

I would like to obtain:

```
Species  Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3
Species_1   1      1         0
Species_2   1      1         1
```

Luis

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{
  if (NR>1) {
   for (C=2; C<=NF; C++) {
     if ($C > 1) {$C=1}
   }
  }
  print
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
NR>1 {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        $i = ($i > 1 ? 1 : $i)
    }
}
1' file | column -t
Species    Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_3
Species_1  1         1         0
Species_2  1         1         1
```

Comment: I  was scribbling in similar lines implementing the ternary operator. Nice touch. The `column -t` is not a requirement though.

Comment: Thanks. Whether or not `column -t` is required depends if the OP really does want to get columnar output like in her posted sample output or not. She asked for it so she got it...

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` way of doing it would be

```
sed -E '2,${s/ 1?[2-9]+/ 1/g;s/ 1[0-9]+/ 1/g}' case_file_48228498 | column -t
Species    Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_3
Species_1  1         1         0
Species_2  1         1         1
```

---

**Edit 1**

I have modified the script above a bit to include the corner cases suggested/found in the comments. The test input contains spaces and tabs to separate the input :

```
# cat case_file_48228498
Species    Sample_1   Sample_2      Sample_3
Species_1   1501      400000         010101
Species_2   10002     00400         00000 
Species_3   20000     100001        000000100044
```

and below is  my modified script

```
# sed -E '2,${s/\s0+([1-9]+)/ \1/;s/\s1?[2-9]+/ 1/g;s/\s([0-1])[0-9]+/ \1/g}'  case_file_48228498 | column -t
Species    Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_3
Species_1  1         1         1
Species_2  1         1         0
Species_3  1         1         1
```

---

<sup>**Note**: Truely what is shown above is an overkill. But there is more to it. As suggested in [**@Ed-Morton**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)'s [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228498/replace-number-larger-than-a-number-in-several-columns/48229286?noredirect=1#comment83444589_48229286) the regex can't replace numeric comparisons as the fail-cases are not immediately visible.</sup>

Comment: That would fail for various input values, e.g. it'd convert `21` to `11`. Best not to try to do numeric comparisons with regexps as there's usually edge cases that fail, just stick with actual numeric comparisons (which means don't use sed for this since it doesn't support numeric comparisons).

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. I did a workaround for the  case you pointed out.. And in principle I completely agree to what you suggested. And though, the user input can't be trusted, I really hope there is no value like `011` for which this would fail.

Comment: You must also hope there is no value like 102, 1002, 10002 or 100002, which get replaced by 12.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Appreciate the sarcastic eyes. I think I have fixed that too. See the edit. ;-)

Comment: That's more like it, I ran a test with 3M values, not a single miss.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille that just proves there's nothing in your current input file that would result in a miss, it doesn't prove there are no values that would result in a miss. I really don't know if there are other cases it won't handle correctly or not but I definitely wouldn't use it for anything I really care about producing the correct output since I couldn't unequivocally state that it WILL handle every case correctly and there are simpler, more robust, and more portable alternatives!